Difference Between Air Data Computer and ADIRU on the Boeing 737

Altitude (ALT) Select or​‬ 1 – enables altitude​ reporting from ‭air‬
‭data‬ computer No. 1.
(FCOM)

What exactly is this “air data computer”? The FCOM doesn’t seem to provide further details on it. Is the air data computer synonymous with the ADIRU? If so, is “air data computer No. 2” the same as “ADIRU-R”?

The air data computer is not synonymous with ADIRU, but it is one of the two components of the ADIRU:

The aircraft is fitted with two (left and right) ADIRUs which are powered from the AC electrical
busses. Each ADIRU includes an IRS and an air data computer which receives information
from separate pitot static sources. The air data part of the ADIRU provides airspeed, Mach
number, angle of attack (AOA), barometric altitude and temperature data. The IRS part of
the ADIRU uses solid state ring laser gyros and X, Y and Z axis accelerometers to provide
information to attitude, FPV and positional data systems.

(Boeing 737-8AS, EI-GJT, serious incident report by the AAIB, emphasis mine)
Honeywell actually calls it "air data function" rather than "computer":

The ADIRU, the heart of the Air Data Inertial Reference System, has two distinct partitions with independent processors.
The air data function calculates critical air data such as airspeed, Mach, angle of attack, air temperature and barometric altitude.
The inertial reference function provides attitude, heading, ground speed and present position data for use in navigation [...]

(Honeywell - Understanding the ADIRU - Video, emphasis mine)
It is a bit strange that the ADIRUs in the 737 are distinguished by side (left or right) and then Boeing uses air data computer No. 1 and No. 2 (instead of left or right). I couldn't find a source that maps these numbers to ADIRUs, but I think it's likely that ADC No. 1 is in ADIRU-L and No. 2 in ADIRU-R.
